# Reviews are being saved to DB, but are not displayed correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Review model, which both belongs to a User and to a Profile. Through a create Action in Reviews Controller, Reviews are being created and saved to the database.

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_profile
  before_action :set_review, only: :new

  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

def create
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
    @review = @profile.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save
        redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)
    else
        redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile), notice: "Didn't save your review"
    end
end

  private

  def review_params
    params.fetch(:review, {}).permit(:rating, :content)
  end

def set_profile
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  end

  def set_review
   @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

If I check with the Console, the Review.last it actually shows the last Review with all the assossiations.

```
#<Review id: 10, rating: 5, content: "Test review", user_id: 3, profile_id: 1, created_at: "2019-11-23 23:50:57", updated_at: "2019-11-23 23:50:57">
```

So the problem is in my Profile#show.erb.html, I guess. For now the review bit looks like this:

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <%= @review.content %> wrote <small> <%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago </small>
    <p>
        <%= @review.content %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

What I get printed is :

```
wrote less than a minute ago
```

... without any content.

So, my guess again, that it doesn't get an access to the params? So might be this line?

```
params.fetch(:review, {}).permit(:rating, :content)
```

But before, as I had it like in the code below, it didn't even save to DB.

```
params.permit(:rating, :content)
```

Also, what doesn't work is accessing the information stored in User. Ideally it should be like this

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <%= @review.user.first_name.last_name %> wrote <small> <%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago </small>
    <p>
        <%= @review.content %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

But when I do so, I get an error

```
undefined method `first_name'
```

I know, that

```
@review.user.first_name.last_name
```

is probably not the right way to display the user's first name and the last name. Ideally it should be

```
John Smith wrote 42 minutes ago : This is a test review
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few mistakes:

The variable within the block is `review`, not `@review`:

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <%= review ... %> wrote <small>
<% end %>
```

Also, `first_name.last_name` is gonna throw a NoMethodError unless you've defined `last_name` on the String class.

Try instead:

```
<%= review.user.first_name %> <%= review.user.last_name %>
```